# Model Channel Distortions in Speech Signals

Tags: audio, signal-processing, speech-recognition, speech

I'm doing a project related to speech processing and I was wondering if there is a way to simulate the effects of channel variations in speech (effects caused by different microphones and such).

Basically I'm wondering if there is some kind of function that takes clean speech as input and outputs a channel distorted signal.

I tried to find some literature but I didn't have much success. any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to better characterize the kind of distortions you need to simulate. Are you looking at just the microphone effects (if so, any specific kinds, vendors, etc, or otherwise know the frequency and transient responses, saturation level, etc), or also nearby environmental effects (echos, reverb, wind, etc.)?

Comment: @SleuthEye I'm looking at the microphone effects only. I'm not really too familiar with this topic so i don't really know how they actually affect the signal. Are these unique to every microphone?